# Getting implemented interfaces from the proxy

Tags: java, scala, reflection, proxy, dynamic-proxy

You normally crate a proxy using

```
val proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(ClassLoader, Class<?>[] interfaces, handler)
```

I am interested in the second parameter because I save created proxies in a list and I want to recreate the proxy with the same interfaces later on. Should I memorize interface classes along with the proxy list or there is a way to map proxy to its implementing interfaces, likewise Proxy.getInvocationHandler(proxy) does for handlers?

Comment: Actually, I needed that for persistence, to recover proxies after program cold restart, and finally realized that there is no need to keep all implemented proxies in main memory for this reason. I can save the interface names only once, when proxy is created for first time and read this DB on restart. Probably, therefore, there are no use cases for what I requested. But, it is curious anyway, if I already started.

Answer (score 2):

`proxy.getClass.getInterfaces`, since `getInterfaces` returns all implemented interfaces and the proxy class implements exactly the interfaces passed to `newInstance`.

Comment: [It says that](http://scastie.org/13325) proxy implements the Class (sic!) alone.

Comment: No, that's just what `Array.toString` for an `Array[Class[_]]` looks like. Use `mkString(", ")` if you want to print it. http://scastie.org/13326